# Does an XML sitemap help indexing flash pages?

Tags: xml, sitemap

Does an XML sitemap help indexing flash pages? I recon it doesn't, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

IF the flash pages map to URLs it does. If it's a flash on the home page that doesn't interact with the url, then no.

Comment: I am afraid it is the second option, so yeah like I assumed it doesn't make any difference in that case - thx for your input Max.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If your sitemapper can crawl the Flash file and retrieve URLs from them, then maybe. (e.g. A1 Sitemap Generator can be configured for Flash which that will work for **some** Flash files.)

Do note: Google can also to some degree crawl Flash files.